# The type 'Icon' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing' in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a Task Manager style application, and in it I would like to get icons for images and display them in a listview. From my research, this seems possible with the `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` function, passing a filename. However, I have run into an issue, whereby the module Icon doesn't seem to exist in System.Drawing. I have found other questions similar to this that suggest adding the reference to the Visual Studio project, however this tab is just not available to me (the Assembly tab, see below).
[image]
Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: From that screen it looks like you are using .NET 5. Dependencies are handled through the NuGet Package Manager. You can right click on you project (Manage NuGet Packages ...) search and install the `System.Drawing.Common` package.

Comment: Yep, that worked completely. Thank you - you might want to write this up to a formal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that screenshot it looks like you are using .NET 5. Dependencies are handled through the NuGet Package Manager. You can right click on you project (Manage NuGet Packages ...) search and install the `System.Drawing.Common` package.